# Facebook Graph API - How to get comments of a video include author?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I always get blank **from** (except comment who made by me) when try get comment from a video although use page access token.

This is my permissions:
[image: This is my permissions]

This is the URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/xxxxxxx/comments?access_token=xxxxxxx&fields=from%7Bname%2Cid%2Clink%7D%2Cid%2Cmessage%2Ccreated_time&limit=500&method=get&order=chronological&pretty=0&sdk=joey&suppress_http_code=1
```

This is the result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "xxxx",
      "message": "Keep 01",
      "created_time": "2021-06-27T03:46:41+0000"
    },
    {
      "from": {
        "name": "xxx",
        "id": "xxx"
      },
      "id": "xxx",
      "message": "KEEP 2311",
      "created_time": "2021-06-27T03:47:19+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "xxx",
      "message": "Keep 132",
      "created_time": "2021-06-27T03:58:06+0000"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "xxx",
      "after": "xxx"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<post_id>/comments?access_token=<access_token>
```

I got 'from' of all comment.